# Add a cell in a table view with a button and dynamic text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, row

I have a string and I want to add a cell in a table view dynamically, with a button, using the string as the button's title.

I have found this code:

```
[self.array addObject:@"string"];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.array.count-1 inSection:0]];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arr withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

But it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this should do the job. But you might have forgotten to do this before:

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```